# Distinguishing between sorting algorithms

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Is there any way to distinguish between sorting algorithms from their executable files? I found this problem in a varsity programming mailing list that goes like this: Say I have a number of executable files that sort an array of data using different algorithms. I know what algorithms are used to code those executables, but I don't know which algorithm was used in which executable file. The algorithms used are:

1. UNAWARE BUBBLE SORT
2. BUBBLE SORT WITH EARLY EXIT
3. TRADITIONAL INSERTION SORT
4. INSERTION SORT ON LIST
5. INSERTION SORT WITH BINARY SEARCH
6. TRADITIONAL SELECTION SORT
7. MERGE SORT
8. TRADITIONAL QUICK SORT
9. QUICK SORT MEDIAN OF THREE
10. RANDOMIZED QUICK SORT
11. SHELL SORT TIMES 4
12. BOGO SORT
13. RADIX SORT LSD FIRST
14. BUCKET SORT
15. COUNTING SORT

Comment: I do not assume that disassembly of the executables is an option?

Comment: the answer is yes.  you can do this by using a number of strategies.  1 - measure memory usage with varying input sizes, 2 - measure run time as a function of input size, 3 - do #2 for pathological inputs

Comment: No @tobias_k I don't think that's an option. It's probably an exercise for learning more about the differences in these algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check their asymptotic behavior by giving them larger and larger input, but many of the listed algorithms fall in the same complexity classes, so you wouldn't be able to distinguish between, say merge sort and quick sort based on this alone.

To break some of these degeneracies you could also look at the memory usage of the different executables, to continue with the merge sort and quick sort example you would see that merge sort would require O(n) additional space while quick sort would only need O(log n) additional space (stack size) to perform the sort.

You might be able to deduce something from giving them degenerate input such as a megabyte of zeros or a megabyte of reversed strings for instance. But you wouldn't be able to do more than educated guesses.

(Excellent comments below. Making this a community wiki, feel free to edit.)

Comment: If he knew it was classical Quicksort, say, he could construct a pathological test case - one where Quicksort would always pick the worst possible pivot - and make a very strong case that this was indeed the algorithm used, if performance is bad. Similar observations can probably be made for other algorithms.

Comment: Would you also be able to distinguish mergesort and quicksort by the memory requirements of the program? As quicksort can be done in O(log n) memory and mergesort needs O(n) additional memory.

Comment: @SimonGibbons quicksort is O(logn) memory (expected stack size)

Answer (score 1):

Change the kinds of data and the amount of data you input and compare execution times.

Changing the nature of the data (repeating small numbers (few digits), vs widely distributed data with no duplicates) helps you determine whether a sorting algorithm is comparison-based, (radix/bucket sort vs comparison-based sorts).  For example, sorting 1000000 1-digit numbers is super fast with bucket sort since it scales mainly off of the number of digits, but slower for comparison-based sorts that scale mainly off the data set size.

You could also tailor the data to perform better for some algorithms over others, like using best case scenario and worst case scenario for the various algorithms and look for the .exe with the most dramatic change in execution time.

For example, to distinguish between insert sort and selection sort, use an *almost* sorted result set like (`2, 3, ...98, 99, 1`).  Insertion sort will do one insert-shift and then the next check will notice that the list is sorted.  This will take almost no time.  Select sort will have to swap at every index, since the minimum will always be at the final index, and this will take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

use the following command in CMD you will find the processing time for each codes with which we can order them.
echo %time%
filename.exe
echo %time%